# Hosting multiple meteor apps on Linode with mup

Tags: node.js, nginx, meteor

I have successfully used mup to deploy a meteor app to a linode instance. In `mup.json` I have specified the `env{}` to have a port of `3000`

With a new app, I set the `port` of `3001` and so adjust my nginx vhost accordingly, but the page gives 502 Bad Gateway. Nginx nginx/1.6.2

Below is the nginx vhost and the mup.json

Any ideas?

Thanks

```
server {
  listen                *:80;

  server_name           example.com;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
}


// mup.json

{
  // Server authentication info
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "109.74.205.44",
      "username": "jonwhittlestone",
       // "password": "password"
       // or pem file (ssh based authentication)
      "pem": "~/.ssh/id_rsa.bak.pub"
    }
  ],

  // Install MongoDB in the server, does not destroy local MongoDB on     future setup
  "setupMongo": false,

  // WARNING: Node.js is required! Only skip if you already have Node.js installed on server.
  "setupNode": true,

  // WARNING: If nodeVersion omitted will setup 0.10.33 by default. Do not use v, only version number.
  "nodeVersion": "0.10.28",

  // Install PhantomJS in the server
  "setupPhantom": true,

  // Application name (No spaces)
  "appName": "example",

  // Location of app (local directory)
  "app": "/Users/jonwhittlestone/code/example",

  // Configure environment
  "env": {
    "ROOT_URL": "http://meteorfreelancer.com",
    "PORT": "3001", // The port you want to bind to on your server.
    "UPSTART_UID": "jonwhittlestone" // The user you want to run meteor as.
  },

  // Meteor Up checks if the app comes online just after the deployment
  // before mup checks that, it will wait for no. of seconds configured below
 "deployCheckWaitTime": 15
}
```

Comment: I cannot curl from the server, so maybe I am not running it correctly

    $ curl localhost:3001
    curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3001: Connection refused

Comment: Does `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` help?